# How to affect candlestick color-up/color-down classes

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to find out how to affect the candlestick classes `highcharts-point-down` and `highcharts-point-up`.
In my screenshot you can see that candles which four values (open, high, low, close) are equal, got the class `highcharts-point-down` applied which is red in my case.

Here is a little example [Code Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jtwosgcz/)
The first three candles are red and have the class `highcharts-point-down` applied, but the price didn't change, (high, open, low, close is 113)

What I want is that those candles which four values are equal (first three in my example) get the class highcharts-point-up. So they appear green not red.

Is there any way to achiev that?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: Sorry, i made one here http://jsfiddle.net/jtwosgcz/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be solved in multiple ways, here are two ways of achieving what you are after:

The most efficient way is to directly change the behavior of the function that decides the class. This is done by [wrapping](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts) the [function that decides on the class](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/js/parts/OHLCSeries.js#L293), like this:

```
(function(H) {
  H.wrap(H.seriesTypes.ohlc.prototype.pointClass.prototype, 'getClassName', function(proceed) {
    return H.Point.prototype.getClassName.call(this) +
      (
        this.open <= this.close ?
        ' highcharts-point-up' :
        ' highcharts-point-down'
      );
  });
}(Highcharts));
```

```js
(function(H) {
  H.wrap(H.seriesTypes.ohlc.prototype.pointClass.prototype, 'getClassName', function(proceed) {
    return H.Point.prototype.getClassName.call(this) +
      (
        this.open <= this.close ?
        ' highcharts-point-up' :
        ' highcharts-point-down'
      );
  });
}(Highcharts));

const data = [
  [
    1477920600000,
    113,
    113,
    113,
    113
  ],
  [
    1478007000000,
    113,
    113,
    113,
    113
  ],
  [
    1478093400000,
    113,
    113,
    113,
    113
  ],
  [
    1478179800000,
    110.98,
    111.46,
    109.55,
    109.83
  ],
  [
    1478266200000,
    108.53,
    110.25,
    108.11,
    108.84
  ],
  [
    1478529000000,
    110.08,
    110.51,
    109.46,
    110.41
  ],
  [
    1478615400000,
    110.31,
    111.72,
    109.7,
    111.06
  ],
  [
    1478701800000,
    109.88,
    111.32,
    108.05,
    110.88
  ],
  [
    1478788200000,
    111.09,
    111.09,
    105.83,
    107.79
  ],
  [
    1478874600000,
    107.12,
    108.87,
    106.55,
    108.43
  ],
  [
    1479133800000,
    107.71,
    107.81,
    104.08,
    105.71
  ],
  [
    1479220200000,
    106.57,
    107.68,
    106.16,
    107.11
  ],
]
// create the chart
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
  rangeSelector: {
    selected: 1
  },

  title: {
    text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
  },

  series: [{
    type: 'candlestick',
    name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
    data: data,
  }]
});
```

```css
.highcharts-point-down {
  fill: red;
  stroke: red;
}

.highcharts-point-up {
  stroke: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
```

The only change done to the original function is changing `<` to be `<=`.

**JSFiddle example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/519myrc2/6/

---

A different way to get what you want is to update the classes at render time:

Add a [`render event`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render), that [`replaces`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/replace) the class for all points where `open == close`. Like this:

```
chart: {
  events: {
    render: function() {
      let points = this.series[0].points;
      for(let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        if(points[i].open == points[i].close) {
          points[i].graphic.element.classList.replace('highcharts-point-down','highcharts-point-up')
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
```

```js
const data = [
[
1477920600000,
113,
113,
113,
113
],
[
1478007000000,
113,
113,
113,
113
],
[
1478093400000,
113,
113,
113,
113
],
[
1478179800000,
110.98,
111.46,
109.55,
109.83
],
[
1478266200000,
108.53,
110.25,
108.11,
108.84
],
[
1478529000000,
110.08,
110.51,
109.46,
110.41
],
[
1478615400000,
110.31,
111.72,
109.7,
111.06
],
[
1478701800000,
109.88,
111.32,
108.05,
110.88
],
[
1478788200000,
111.09,
111.09,
105.83,
107.79
],
[
1478874600000,
107.12,
108.87,
106.55,
108.43
],
[
1479133800000,
107.71,
107.81,
104.08,
105.71
],
[
1479220200000,
106.57,
107.68,
106.16,
107.11
],]
    // create the chart
    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    chart: {
         events: {
           render: function() {
             let points = this.series[0].points;
              
             for(let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
               if(points[i].open == points[i].close) {
                 points[i].graphic.element.classList.replace('highcharts-point-down','highcharts-point-up')
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        title: {
            text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
        },

        series: [{
            type: 'candlestick',
            name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
            data: data,
        }]
    });
```

```css
.highcharts-point-down {
  fill: red;
  stroke: red;
}

.highcharts-point-up {
  stroke: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
```

**JSFiddle example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/jtwosgcz/14/

Comment: Thanks, that's it! Would there be a way to achiev the same result without looping all the series points and replacing the classes?

Comment: @Pad I have added how to perform the wrapping of the function and a working example. This would be the most efficient way you can achieve what you are after.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your help, i implemented it like u advised.